# Setting .as file to be actionscript instead of applesingle archive

Tags: macos, finder, actionscript

When I save a file as something.as, OSX thinks it's an applesingle archive and when I open it it tries to unzip it.

Is there a way I can tell OSX that .as files are actionscript and not applesingle archives?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click or command-click any **.as** file, choose *Get Info* , then in the info window that appears, expand the "Open With" section, choose the appropriate program (e.g. FlexBuilder, the Flash authoring tool, or your favorite text editor perhaps!), and then click the "Change All" button. That should do what you want.

Comment: That's what I first tried, but there's a bug, when I click the Change All button it just returns to open with archive utility.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, it works for me.  I was just able to change .as files default command on my system from Dreamwaver to Flash CS3.  I'm on Snow Leopard.  What are you on - Leopard, Tiger, etc.?

Comment: I'm on the latest version of Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

next time install the archiver and after try to install Flash, so this way Flash will be the last to modify the file association (this is just an ideea, it might work). Or you can uninstall and re-install Adobe Flash